# Putting 8 rooks on a $14\times14$ table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm wondering how to count putting $8$ rooks on a $14\times14$ chess table so that top left and top right field can't be used, and they don't attack each other (not being in a same row/column).

I used a base example for $8\times8$ table and expanded it to a $14\times14$ table, and excluded the $2$ fields as mentioned, so can my answer be $P(13,6)+8*26$ ?

Comment: Hi welcome to math stackexchange! Are you trying to count the number of ways you can put 8 rooks on a 14x14 board or just want to know if it is possible? What do you mean by $P(13,6)$? Do you mean $P(13,6)=13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8$?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to count them but I guess I forgot to mention it. And, yes, that is what I had in mind for P(13,6).

Comment: When you exclude two fields, are those just two of the squares on the board?  $P(13,6)$ is the number of ways to put $6$ rooks on a $13 \times 13$ board.  You have to place all $8$ rooks.  I don't understand the $8 * 26$ at all.

Comment: I was thinking that for every rook there is 2*13 more possibilities to the P(13,6) possibilities, so 8 times 26

Comment: That is not correct because you are insisting that two rooks be in the outer columns and you should multiply possibilities, not add them.  You are not including the cases where all $8$ rooks are in the middle $12$ columns and you are counting cases where one of the outer rooks is in the same row as one of the inner rooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier is to count all the ways to put $8$ rooks on a full $14 \times 14$ board and subtract the ones that have a rook in one of the forbidden squares.  There are $P(14,8)$ ways to place $8$ rooks on a $14 \times 14$ board.  If we start with one in the top left, there are $P(13,7)$ ways to place the rest.  Similarly if there is one in the top right there are $P(13,7)$ ways to place the rest.  There are then $P(14,8)-2P(13,7)$ ways to place the rooks as you require.  Note that this depends on the fact that you cannot place rooks in both the top left and top right as they would attack each other.  If you could, we would have subtracted those cases twice and would have to add them back once.